# What's the opposite of "Rest In Peace"?

Tags: phrase-requests, antonyms

If you want to express hate about someone that passed away, how would you say that?

Comment: @Jasper Loy +1, I know, but sometimes you gotta write a letter :P

Comment: exhausted out chaos

Comment: Related: it is common (at least in movies and TV), when a prisoner is executed, for the executioner to say “may God have mercy on your soul”. Saying something along those lines could be a more subtle way of expressing a negative opinion about the deceased.

Comment: @nogat "May God torture your soul" - makes sense?

Comment: I hope you _die in a fire_?

Comment: Good idea but I'm talking to someone that is already dead... Let's make it "May your grave burn in fire" or even "May your corpse burn in fire".

Comment: Reading the answers below, it occurs to me that the question is how nasty you want to be. "May he burn in Hell" is pretty severe. I think "I dance on his grave" is less so, but still pretty nasty. "Good riddance" and "Rest in pieces" are far more mild. "May God have mercy on his soul" expresses disdain without saying you actually wish him ill.

Comment: Writhe in agony. :-)

Comment: @Jay, Yes, I wanted it to sound as harsh and nasty as possible...

Comment: @Shimmy how about  "rot in hell" or .. not a traditional english phrase, but good english and the english of the hebrew phrase ymach shmo vezichroh! "may his name and memory be obliterated" or as same preacher said of arafat "May his bones be crushed". (though I think arafat was alive at the time!).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's also "rest in pieces."

Comment: That's a good one! That's actually the one I was after! It's both insulting and funny.

Answer (score 30):

There are a range of curses which would express such a sentiment, partly affected by religious belief, so "be reincarnated as a cockroach" might be suitable for those who think such a thing is possible.

The most common Christian antonym is probably "burn in hell", particularly in opposition to the modern prayer: "May they rest in peace, and rise in glory" which is replacing the older "Rest eternal grant unto them O Lord and may light perpetual shine upon them"

Comment: I think I'll go for plain old "burn in hell". unless you got a better one, I want it to be simple, not to verbose.

Comment: Or "rot in Hell".

Comment: +1. I've seen illustrations of mock gravestones with B.I.H. at the top where you'd typically see R.I.P. It didn't take much thought to work out what that stood for.

Comment: If you just want to be nasty and insulting, I don't think it would matter if you, the deceased, or whomever you're talking to actually believe that the curse you pronounce is theologically accurate. Like, if you say to an atheist, "May Fred burn in Hell", I think he'll get the idea that you didn't like Fred, even though he doesn't believe in such a place as Hell. Even if the hearer believes in the religious idea behind your curse, I think few would suppose you actually have the power to control how somehow is reincarnated or where he spends eternity.

Answer (score 13):

"Good riddance"? There are an awful lot of ways you could express that sentiment.

Comment: Why wouldn't you quote some of them, I know there are a lot.

Answer (score 6):

"Pissing on their grave" or "Dancing on their grave" always resonated with me...

Comment: OMG I lolled from both the answer and the comment

Answer (score 4):

In the early 19th century, the death of Britain's King George IV didn't get much sympathy.  [The following verse circulated](http://www.explore-parliament.net/nssMovies/01/0148/0148_.htm):

> *George the First was always reckoned
>
>   Vile, but viler George the Second
>
>   And what mortal ever heard
>
>   Any good of George the Third?
>
>   When from Earth the fourth descended
>
>   God be praised, the Georges ended.*
>
> – Walter Savage Landor, 1775–1864

Actually there were two more in the 20th century, both quite decent and popular.

Comment: While this is a good quotation, it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: To future visitors: Please be aware that this is not how answers should be given. It can stay due to how old it is.